# Chcekboxes in XML/XSLT Table

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a Problem creating checkboxes in my table in my XML XSL files. It doesn't work...

My XML:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<mobCheckbox>
  <tr>
    <td><button name="mobilitaet" value="tlwUnterstuetzung" />teilweise Unterstützung</td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td><button name="mobilitaet" value="vollstUnterstuetzung" />vollständige Unterstützung</td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td><button name="mobilitaet" value="KontrolleAufsicht" />Kontrolle und Aufsicht</td></tr>

</mobCheckbox>
</tbody>
</table>
```

"mobCheckbox" is defined in my XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="n1:mobCheckbox" mode="form-construct">
        <form xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
                <xsl:apply-templates mode="form-construct" /> 
                <xsl:for-each select="n1:button[@name='mobilitaet']">       
                    <input xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" type="checkbox" name="mobilitaet"></input>
                </xsl:for-each>  
        </form> 
  </xsl:template>
```

Can somebody please help me? I don't know what is wrong, i just want some checkboxes where my "Buttons" are. Hope you understand my bad english...

Best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your source XML is actually a fragment and has a default namespace declared:

```
<parent xmlns="namespace">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <mobCheckbox>
    ...
```

And you have that namespace mapped to the `n1` prefix in XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:n1="namespace" version="1.0">
....
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I also assume that the rest of your XSLT stylesheet is functioning correctly and you have other templates to deal with the nodes you are not using.

You are not selecting anything in the `for-each` block because in the *context* of `n1:mobCheckbox` there is no child `n1:button`. You have to consider the two elements `n1:tr` and `n1:td` that are between `n1:mobCheckbox` and `n1:button` in your `for-each`. You can either explicitly declare them in your XPath expression:

```
<xsl:for-each select="n1:tr/n1:td/n1:button[@name='mobilitaet']">       
    <input xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" type="checkbox" name="mobilitaet"></input>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Or you can use a `descendant-or-self` shortcut: `//n1:button[@name='mobilitaet']`.

Answer (score 0):

The elements are descendants, not children of the context node. I would replace

```
<xsl:template match="n1:mobCheckbox" mode="form-construct">
        <form xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
                <xsl:apply-templates mode="form-construct" /> 
                <xsl:for-each select="n1:button[@name='mobilitaet']">       
                    <input xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" type="checkbox" name="mobilitaet"></input>
                </xsl:for-each>  
        </form> 
  </xsl:template>
```

with

```
<xsl:template match="n1:mobCheckbox" mode="form-construct">
        <form xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
                <xsl:apply-templates mode="form-construct" /> 

        </form> 
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="n1:button[@name='mobilitaet']" mode="form-construct">

                    <input xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" type="checkbox" name="mobilitaet"></input>
</xsl:template>
```

If you put the `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` on the root of the stylesheet you don't have to put it on every result element.